# Why is Firefox saying that my website is using an "invalid security certificate"?

Tags: firefox, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have been using a wildcard SSL certificate for several of my company's B2B websites for some time. Recently, we noticed that Google Chrome started displaying a red unlocked lock with HTTPS crossed out for all of these websites. The solution I found was to reissue the certificate from the provider (Network Solutions). So, I did this, and updated the certificate for each of the websites, and the Google Chrome issue went away (HOORAY!). However, when visiting any of these websites in Firefox, it displays a security message stating the website is using an invalid security certificate:

[image]

How can I resolve this so that our users are not confused when visiting these websites?

P.S. These websites are running on **IIS6**.

Comment: Did you update the certificate chain bundle when you updated the certificate?  Posting the results of the test above @MrTux noted would be helpful.

Comment: It's not clear that the same CA certificate is used when you updated your certificate, thus, it's recommended to update/check the chain everytime you exchange a certificate.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if the certificate chain is incomplete and, thus, Firefox (and likely other browsers) cannot verify the site certificate. Normally browsers store intermediate certificates they have seen in the past - that might be a reason why it works in Chrome.

You can test using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html.

Depending on the server software (here, for Apache httpd and other servers which read the certificate in PEM/DER format), you can just paste the intermediate certificates together with the certificate in one .pem file (which is used as Certificate file).

The chain (intermediate certificates) is/are normally provided by your CA. In your case you could also use Chrome the review the certificate and then store/extract all intermediate certificates from the certificate view.

Comment: thank you, I ran it and it looks like the intermediate certs are not complete. Not sure how to install these (I thought I did) or ensure they are included with the server response....

Comment: I added a note on how to fix this.

Comment: Using IIS6. I seriously have no clue how to do this.... Any additional help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just google for "iis intermedia certificate" (I don't run IIS)

Comment: Ok, I followed the instructions at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/954755, and can see the certificates in the MMC, but I'm still getting the error in Firefox.

Comment: KB954755 is about server authentication (clients authenticate using a certificate), maybe better https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4875 or https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4801/

Comment: In IIS, there is an option under Directory Security to "Enable certificate trust list". I enabled it and added the "AddTrust External CA Root" to the CTL certificates list and this appears to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can get ***this certificate is not trusted*** error if server doesn't send a required intermediate certificate.

Firefox automatically stores intermediate certificates that servers send in the Certificate Manager for future usage.
If a server doesn't send a full certificate chain then you won't get an untrusted error when Firefox has stored missing intermediate certificates from visiting a server in the past that has send it, but you do get an untrusted error if this intermediate certificate isn't stored yet.

You can inspect the certificate chain via a site like this:

http://www.networking4all.com/en/support/tools/site+check/

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions at [enter link description here](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/954755), to import the intermediate certificates.

In IIS, there is an option under Directory Security to "Enable certificate trust list". I enabled it and added the "AddTrust External CA Root" to the CTL certificates list and this appears to have fixed the issue.